Como conseguir que duas aplicações Java de gerações diferentes alimentem a mesma base mysql com campos autoincremento
Possuo uma aplicação Java legada usando JPA com uma base de dados Mysql. Tenho acesso aos fontes, mais para consulta, mas porém tenho como fazer qualquer alteração, nem construíla de novo para criar uma nova versão.
Na expectativa de conseguir utilizar ambas as aplicações simultaneamente de modo a permitir uma migração gradual das funcionalidades, estou tentando fazer uma nova aplicação, desta vez usando o Quarkus. Configurei o acesso, apontei para a mesma base de aplicação legada, mapeei as entidades da mesma forma que estavam mapeadas na aplicação antiga e, nas consultas, tudo deu certo.
O problema é que nessa aplicação legada, a maioria das entidades possui chaves primárias declarados como do tipo autoincremento com a anotação @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO).
Com isso, quando eu, por exemplo, (a partir da base vazia), cadastro inicialmente um produto, seu id é definido como 1. Ao cadastrar um cliente, seu id fica gravado como 2. Gravando, depois disso, um novo produto, o id fica 3.
De alguma forma, em algum lugar da base de dados, o mysql guarda um atributo com esse contador, que acumula o autoincremento de todas as tabelas do sistema. Parece ser um lugar único, para todas as tabelas.
Acontece que na aplicação nova com o Quarkus usando o Panache, a mesma declaração de atributo produz um comportamento diferente, gerando um numero que nao coincide com o ultimo registro criado pela aplicação antiga.
Tentei fazer esse controle via aplicação mesmo, lá no Quarkus, buscando o ultimo id da tabela e atribuindo manualmente esse valor no objeto, antes de grava-lo. Ele até gravou, porém nao atualizou esse atributo que guarda a sequencia. Aí quanto fui gravar um novo registro na aplicação antiga, recebo o erro “chave primária duplicada” porque obviamente a aplicação legada não “soube” da criação do novo id na aplicação nova.
Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de duas aplicações diferentes, alimentarem a mesma base de dados mysql, sem essas incompatibilidades. Pensei até em atualizar "manualmente" esse atributo na nova aplicação, mas não sei como poderia fazer isso.
Caso alguém tenha alguma outra ideia, eu ficaria imensamente agradecido.
